# Running WCF Test Client and receiving MaxReceivedMessageSize error after increasing in app.config

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio, wcf-binding

I am trying to set up my first WCF service in VS 2013. I'm busy working my way through a tutorial, but have hit a snag...

Running a simple Service (DataViewerService) which calls out to a database to return a recordset. I have changed my bindings to:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding allowCookies="true"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000"
             maxBufferSize="20000000"
             maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
           maxArrayLength="200000000"
           maxStringContentLength="200000000"/>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

within system.serviceModel, and directly below I have included

```
<services>
  <service name="DataViewerService.Service1">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/DataViewerService/Service1/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:2112/Viewer" 
              binding="basicHttpBinding" 
              contract="DataViewerService.IService1"> 
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Having googled around, all I read is that the client and server both need to be set... However, I am running on localhost, and I am consuming within the wcf Test Client. I can't seem to figure out where else I need to make these changes... What the heck am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]You need to edit the config on the WCF Test client.

Right at the bottom of your added service you will see a node called "Config file".

Try minimizing your contract to see it

Comment: In my Solution Explorer under my Service, I see six nodes: Properties, References, App.config, IService1.cs, packages.config, and Service1.cs. I made the changes already in App.config... I see no other nodes indicating config.

Comment: Not your service, the client that connects to your service (has the 'service reference' or 'client')

Comment: Not in your solution - in your WCF Test client.

Comment: Ive updated the post with a screenshot. The wcf test client is a client and it will use defaults - you will need to edit these defaults

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  I am sure it used to....Windows 10? Visual Studio 2013