# maxreceivedmessagesize error even with all configurations

Tags: wcf, maxreceivedmessagesize

I have a problem with the MaxReceivedMessageSize attribute, I have all the settings done, but I keep getting the message related to value exceeded (65536)

Can you help me identify the problem in the configuration?
Thank you

This is my web.config file

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="Binding1" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00"
      receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
      hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
      maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
      textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
      messageEncoding="Text">
      <security mode="None" />
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxDepth="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="saam.mdlw.srv.aep.SerBehavior" name="saam.mdlw.srv.aep.aep">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Binding1" behaviorConfiguration="saam.mdlw.srv.aep.EndBehavior" contract="saam.mdlw.srv.aep.Isrv_aep" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="saam.mdlw.srv.aep.EndBehavior">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="saam.mdlw.srv.aep.SerBehavior">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: You need to apply the same limits to your client.

Comment: but I'm testing with wct test client ... even so you should set? where?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236905/running-wcf-test-client-and-receiving-maxreceivedmessagesize-error-after-increas

Comment: Works Perfect! Thanks! :D